# Selenium using Python - Storing screenshot in folder with date and timestamp

Tags: selenium

Using Selenium with Python, I am trying to take screenshot and saving them in a folder which
has date and timestamp but nothing is getting saved in the folder. This is the code snippet:

Folder creation activity:

```py
path = 'C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\ADF'
DateString = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
os.chdir(path)
NewFolder = 'PBI_' + DateString
os.makedirs(NewFolder)
```

To save the screenshot, I am using:

```py
driver.save_screenshot(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), NewFolder,'Before_Authentication.png'))
```

Folder name "NewFolder" is getting created successfully but no screenshot is present here.

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime
path = 'C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\ADF'
DateString = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
os.chdir(path)
NewFolder = 'PBI_' + DateString
os.makedirs(NewFolder)
driver.save_screenshot(NewFolder+'/foo.png')
```

Seems to create the file just fine just append the file name to the new folder.

Comment: Thank you so much Arun, it worked !!!!

Comment: No problem accept the answer if it helped.